# Scraping with requests_html randomly gives (no) result from JS site. Timing issue?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I want to scrape data from IMDb. Since beautifulsoup4 cannot work with JavaScript, I use html_request.
However, my code randomly gives (no) result. When I repeat the same code 10 times, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. time.sleep() does not help (I thought maybe JS needs longer to be loaded).
Why is that and how to fix?

```
# from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4236770/')
# time.sleep(1)
rating_show = r.html.find('.AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1il8omz-1')[0] # either works or 'list index out of range' error
rating_show = float(rating_show.text)
rating_show
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the class and structure of the page are changing to avoid scraping. It is not due to javascript rendering.

By the way if you want to render the page you need to use render method `r.html.render()` after the get request.

Here you can just bypass the class in order to get the notation of the film like this:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4236770/')

body = r.html.text
indice = body.find('/10')

print(body[indice - 3: indice])

# output: Always return '8.6'
```

Comment: Thank you! Confusing bc when I manually check the website, the class name always was the same.
How did you come up with the '/10`?
Using r.html.render() results in "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.". A common problem according to google - not sure how to fix it (using VSC/Jupyter)